# python selenium hidden frame

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I am trying to make an application that automatically posts in blogspot. I could come up with Selenium a while ago. My problem is click on the Upload image button to open a new frame. I am trying to switch a frame, but the frame name changes every time the page is opened. The only thing that does not change is the frame  in class name. The `iframe` field of the page appears to be disabled when the page is first opened.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

delay=10
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python34\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=blogID#allposts/src=sidebar')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def start():
    email=wait.until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id('Email'))
    email.clear()
    email.send_keys('gmailaccound')
    ileri=wait.until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id('next'))
    ileri.click()
# WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id('next')))

    password=wait.until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id('Passwd'))
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys('password')
    ileri2=wait.until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id('signIn'))
    ileri2.click()

    yeni_yayin=wait.until(lambda  driver:driver.find_element_by_class_name('OYKEW4D-i-x'))
    yeni_yayin.click()
    time.sleep(5)                
    resim_buton=wait.until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.tr-image').click())
    time.sleep(5)


    iframe=driver.find_element_by_class_name('picker-frame')

    driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

[image: iframe screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the `name` of the iframe then switch to iframe by name, see the following:

```
if_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[class='picker-frame']").get_attribute("name")
driver.switch_to_frame(if_name)
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (635, 132). Other element would receive the click: <div class="picker modal-dialog-bg" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 0.5; width: 1100px; height: 920px;"></div>

Comment: you are trying to click hidden element check your log: `hidden="true"`